# TypeScript Discord.js error while trying to get events

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm having a compile-time error while trying to set my Discord.js dynamic events from TypeScript

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(event: keyof ClientEvents, listener: (...args: [client: Client<true>] | [data: ApplicationCommandPermissionsUpdateData] | [autoModerationActionExecution: AutoModerationActionExecution] | ... 69 more ... | [guildScheduledEvent: ...]) => Awaitable<...>): Client<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(...args: unknown[]) => unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: [client: Client<true>] | [data: ApplicationCommandPermissionsUpdateData] | [autoModerationActionExecution: AutoModerationActionExecution] | ... 69 more ... | [guildScheduledEvent: ...]) => Awaitable<...>'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<void>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(event: never, listener: (...args: any[]) => Awaitable<void>): Client<boolean>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2769)
```

The method below is what is causing the issue and it's placed in the **index.ts** file, is called **eventObjectAdderModerator**

```js
const eventObjectAdderModerator = (event: ReadableEventObject, filePath: string): void => {
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, event.execute);
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, event.execute);
    }
};
```

Extra details of my implementation are provided below:

The method that is *interacting* with the **eventObjectAdderModerator** method is this one:

```js
// Fetch event objects.
const eventFetchResolver = async () => {
    const crawler = new FileCrawler(path.join(__dirname, 'core/models/events'), '.js', true);
    const eventFiles = await crawler.crawl();
    for (const eventFile of eventFiles) {
        const eventObject = await ObjectFetcher.read(eventFile);
        let event: ReadableEventObject;
        if (eventObject instanceof ReadableEventObject) {
            event = eventObject;
            eventObjectAdderModerator(event, eventFile);
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see it is trying to get a file collection using the custom crawler and then it looks if the class requested is matching with a *ReadableEventObject*, if that is the case is trying to get it and send it to the **eventObjectAdderModerator**

These are the details regarding the implementation of *ReadableEventObject* class

```js
import Event from '../../core/models/events/event';
import type IReadableObject from './IReadableObject';

abstract class ReadableEventObject extends Event implements IReadableObject {
    abstract getReadableData (): unknown;
}

export default ReadableEventObject;
```

As you can see it inherits from the custom Event class that I made, where the implementation is defined for every new Event added.

Finally this is the code of the Event class where I think there is the issue.

```js
import { type ClientEvents } from 'discord.js';

export default abstract class Event {
    abstract name: keyof ClientEvents;
    abstract once: boolean;
    abstract execute (...args: unknown[]): unknown;
}
```

I have been trying to get it, actually it seems like there is a lot of possible overloads, so I'm thinking I may need to have something more flexible than this.

I tried to change the signature in the Events class but after doing it was showing other errors.